# Convert VB6 Code Calls to Windows DLL to PHP FFI

Tags: php, c, ffi

I have working VB6 code using MS Access to call a dll.  I would like to convert it to PHP FFI.

```
Public Declare Function UNZ_INIT_EX Lib "UNZDLL32.DLL" () As Long
Public Declare Function UNZ_TERM Lib "UNZDLL32.DLL" (ByVal hUnz As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function UNZ_CHECKADDRESS Lib "UNZDLL32.DLL" (ByVal hUnz As Long, ByVal Line1$, ByVal     Line2$, ByVal Line3$, ByVal Line4$) As Long
Public Declare Function UNZ_GETSTDADDRESS Lib "UNZDLL32.DLL" (ByVal hUnz As Long, ByVal szFirmName As   String, ByVal szPRUrb As String, ByVal szDelLine As String, ByVal szLastLine As String) As Long

Dim hUnz As Long
Dim szFirmName As String * 51      ' ** All Fixed Sized Are To 51    Default
Dim szPRUrb As String * 51
Dim szDelLine As String * 51
Dim szLastLine As String * 51
Dim szCity As String * 51
Dim szState As String * 51
Dim szZIP As String * 51
Dim result As Long
Dim Line1 As String, Line2 As String, Line3 As String, Line4 As String
Dim retAry(0 To 34) As String

hUnz = UNZ_INIT_EX() 'returns 1 on success, 0 on failure
result = UNZ_TERM(hUnz) ' returns 1 if successful

Line1 = ''          ' no firm name
Line2 = ''          ' no Puerto Rico addresses in this address
Line3 = '1234 Main St'  ' this is the street address
Line4 = "Some City' & ", " & ST & " " & '12345'    'build city-st-zip

result = UNZ_CHECKADDRESS(hUnz, Line1, Line2, Line3, Line4)
retAry(8) = CStr(result) 'error code as integer

result = UNZ_GETSTDADDRESS(hUnz, szFirmName, szPRUrb, szDelLine, szLastLine)
retAry(1)  = FixedToVar(szDelLine) 'street address
retAry(29) = FixedToVar(szFirmName)
retAry(30) = FixedToVar(szPRUrb)
retAry(2)  = FixedToVar(szLastLine) 'city-st-zip
```

I tried the following PHP FFI:

```
$ffi = FFI::cdef(
    "int32_t UNZ_INIT_EX();
     long int UNZ_CHECKADDRESS(int32_t*, char *str, char *str, char *str, char *str);
     long int UNZ_GETSTDADDRESS(int32_t);
     long int UNZ_TERM(int32_t*);
     long int UNZ_ERROR();",
   "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\unzdll64.dll");
$hunz = $ffi->UNZ_INIT_EX();
echo "hunz: $hunz";
```

Calling UNZ_INIT_EX returns a number like `168349344`.

```
$term = $ffi->UNZ_TERM($hunz);
```

Trying to call the terminate function I receive an error:
Fatal error: Uncaught FFI\Exception: Passing incompatible argument 1 of C function 'UNZ_TERM', expecting 'int32_t*', found PHP 'int' ...

I get the same error when calling UNZ_CHECKADDRESS.  I need some guidance in creating the FFI field definitions of int_32t and the string references.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fatal error: Uncaught FFI\Exception: Passing incompatible argument 1 of C function 'UNZ_TERM', expecting 'int32_t*', found PHP 'int'

The function is expecting a pointer and your are passing the int value. Create the parameter as following:

```php
<?php

$ffi = FFI::cdef(
    "int32_t UNZ_INIT_EX();
     long int UNZ_CHECKADDRESS(int32_t*, char *str, char *str, char *str, char *str);
     long int UNZ_GETSTDADDRESS(int32_t);
     long int UNZ_TERM(int32_t*);
     long int UNZ_ERROR();",
   "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\unzdll64.dll"
);
$hunz = $ffi->UNZ_INIT_EX();

// Fetch the variable's address
$hunzPointer = \FFI::addr($hunz);
$term = $ffi->UNZ_TERM($hunzPointer);
```

That will pass the pointer as argument, instead of passing the int value.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  This helped get rid of the error.  Now the UNZ_CHECKADDRESS function returns no data (empty result).  I will work on this next.

Comment: @Landrew , if this solved your original problem, don't forget to mark the answer as correct. If you have a new question, feel free to create it separately. :-)